# Get next ResultSet in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have 2 queries and therefore 2 `ResultSet`'s returned from MySQL in Java through `createStatement()`. The queries are like

```sql
SELECT * FROM abc;
SELECT * FROM def;
```

These queries are run simultaneously in single `createStatement()` like

```
CreateConnection();
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from ABC; select * from DEF;");
while(rs.next()) {
    //Iterate through first resultset 
}
rs.close();
stat.close();
conn.close();
```

How can I get the next `ResultSet` returned by second query?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to just do 2 statements/queries?

Comment: @getlost won't that do a join, and return n^2 rows rather than 2n?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes i just forget it

Comment: its simple because my first query is totally different and cannot be merged or joined with second query and instead of creating another connection for second query it's better to execute both queries in single executeQuery() and move to next resultset just like we do in PHP and python

Comment: you don't need to create another connection

Comment: In java the connection is not closed in between, so twice an executeQuery is not really suboptimal, as opposed to PHP where you are right.

Comment: Ok I got it, I can use single connection and multiple stat.executeQuery() but isn't there a way to move to next resultset like PHP or Phython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Statement#getMoreResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--) and [`Statement#getResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet--) methods:

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from ABC; select * from DEF;");
while(rs.next()) {
    //Iterate through first resultset 
}
rs.close();
if (stat.getMoreResults()) {
    rs = stat.getResultSet();
    while(rs.next()) {
        //Iterate through second resultset 
    }
}
stat.close();
```

In order that make this method to work, you should add `allowMultiQueries=true` property to your connection by appending this property to your connection url:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://yourServer:yourPort/yourDatabase?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

---

Note that you can perform multiple queries per `Statement` using a single `Connection` object:

```
Connection con = ...
List<String> sqlStatements = ... //a list with all the SELECT statements you have
for (String query : sqlStatements) {
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        //do your logic here...
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
conn.close();
```

Comment: your first method doesn't work and other thing is that you are closing resultset **(rs.close();)** and then trying to get another resultset from same object of rs.

Comment: @JavaDrunk: Even when getting _another_ ResultSet through `Statement.getResultSet()` the previous one _should_ be closed properly. And the first method works - at least in MySQL which the OP is using.